# angular-compilers seems not working with 'paths' in tsconfig

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, tsconfig

https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/tree/master/atmosphere-packages/angular-compilers

I am using `paths` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` in order to shorten my import path but seems that the compiler cannot resolve the module path during compilation. Is there any options to set the alias path in `angular-compilers`?

I think my `paths` for non-relative module path is incorrect, how to set it correctly?

P.S. in VS code, no errors :v

**import syntax**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { AppModule } from '~/client/core/app.module';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "es5",
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "inlineSourceMap": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "stripInternal": true,
  "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "scripthost"],
  "paths": {
    "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"],
    "~/*": ["src/*"]
  },
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

**output error**

```
/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.7.0_3.o37tid.7k2h++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
            throw(ex);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module '/node_modules/@angular/core/core'
    at makeMissingError (packages/modules-runtime.js:208:12)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:227:17)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
    at email-toolbar.js (src/both/classes/email-toolbar.ts:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:322:7)
    at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:224:14)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:244:21)
    at src/server/main.ts:12:2
    at ...
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```